# Null object reference on setText in Android app

Tags: java, android, textview

My app crashes on this `setText` here. I think probably because it cannot find the id so I looked into to R.java  and found the id there. I'm confused why it still crashes.

```
TextView city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_result);
city.setText(msg[0]);
```

R.java

```
public static final int city_result=0x7f080041;
```

and this code is in the `public static final class id` method.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!!

================
More Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_report);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    //get message from intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String[] message = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    setResult(message);
}
public void setResult(String[] msg)
    {
        //test
        TextView city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_result);
        city.setText(msg[0]);
    }
```

This file I just started, elsewhere is just system generated new file code, I didn't edit yet.
Here's logcat:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chen.weather/com.example.chen.weather.WeatherReport}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.chen.weather.WeatherReport.setResult(WeatherReport.java:78)
            at com.example.chen.weather.WeatherReport.onCreate(WeatherReport.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: show more code where `TextView city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_result);` line is used

Comment: Show the log report.

Comment: "_My app crashes_" doesn't mean much on it's own. Post logcat output, indicate the line of code producing the error/exception, show us `msg` and how it is created and populated ....

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  I just started and this is the only place where textview shows up.

Comment: @Zip: please post more code

Comment: @amitsingh  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chen.weather/com.example.chen.weather.WeatherReport}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)` ....... `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at )` ...

Answer (score 15):

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText

Means `city` TextView object is `null` due to :

**1.** `setContentView` is not called before using `findViewById`:

**2.** Not using layout in which `TextView` is defined with `city_result` id. make sure you are passing right layout in `setContentView`

Comment: I'm really new to android. I'm using `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_report);` Is this the right one? That should be the filename of the xml file related to this java file.

Comment: @Zip: In which layout you have `TextView` with city_result id. ?

Comment: activity_weather_report.xml

Comment: @Zip: post `activity_weather_report.xml` layout xml code

Comment: I just restart my android studio and it works! I don't know why but there's no more crash. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK.would you please answer my question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40817284/4568864

Answer (score 3):

check that your activity is correct!!

setContentView(R.layout.**activity_weather_report**);

Answer (score 1):

Which layout did you put the TextView? I doubt that in this case, you put the TextView in PlaceHolder fragment layout (not the `activity_weather_report.xml` layout). If so, putting the TextView in `activity_weather_report.xml` will solve your problem.

Comment: I just checked and it seems that something wrong with android studio, I restart it and it works. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is just the `id`**

Make sure that you are using correct id for `TextView` in Layout `xml` file .
I had same issue and it resolved by solving spelling mistake .

Answer (score 0):

it is showing this exception because your textview is not getting data at time of onCeate method.
declare your textview in onCreate method, 
put yourtextview.setText(xyz) wherever you are getting that "xyz" value.
Hope this will work.