# 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference but only in Release Mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This problem occurs when I try to open any `Option Menu` but only in **Release Mode**. In Debug Mode everything works as expected.

Error log from ADB:

```
01-31 01:55:58.587  5986  5986 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.pokinia.app, PID: 5986
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.setTitle(ListMenuItemView.java:117)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView.initialize(ListMenuItemView.java:104)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getView(MenuPopupHelper.java:381)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.measureContentWidth(MenuPopupHelper.java:223)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:157)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:785)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-31 01:55:58.613  5986  5986 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

As stated in many other threads this means that some value is null but as it's working in Debug I'm not sure how to figure out what's going on.

[Null object reference on setText in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248220/null-object-reference-on-settext-in-android-app)

My toolbar:

```
mToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

How can I figure out which property is causing this if the problem only appears in Release Mode?

Comment: can you post `ListMenuItemView.java`?

Comment: What is your `Linker` setting in Release builds and do you have `Proguard` enabled?

Comment: @vrundpurohit `ListMenuItemView.java` is not custom class, it is in support lib: `android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

- Clean the Solution
- Rebuild the Solution